# Duplicate identifier error with d.ts file and nodejs require with same name

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, tsc

Now I am sure the issue is because there is a d.ts file included which contains a module called "Shared", and a require statement which includes a variable of the same name if it is being used in a NodeJS environment.

```
// shared.d.ts
declare module Shared { ... }

// other_module.ts
/// <reference path="shared.d.ts"/>
if(require) { var Shared = require("shared"); }
export class Something {
    public someVar = new Shared.SomethingElse("blah");
}
```

So when I compile `other_module.ts` (which is actually a lot of separate files), it tells me Shared is a duplicate identifier, which I can understand as TS thinks Shared is a module, but then is being told it is the return of require.

The problem here is that the output of modules need to be compatible with nodeJS's require system, so in this case when other_module is required it will be in its own scope and will not know about `Shared.SomethingElse` so the require is needed so the internal modules in `other_module` will be able to access the Shared library, but in the browser environment it would get `Shared.SomethingElse` via the global scope.

If I remove the reference then the file wont compile as it doesn't know about `Shared`, if I remove the require when the module is loaded into nodejs (`var otherModule = require("other_module")`) it will complain that it doesn't know about `Shared`. So is there a way to solve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## First the error

Duplicate identifier because you have `Shared` in `shared.d.ts` + in `other_module.ts`.

## FIX A, be all external

If you want to use `amd` / `commonjs` ie. **external modules**, you need to use `import/require` (not `var/require` like you are doing). Using an `import` creates a new variable **declaration space** and therefore you are no longer polluting the global namespace `Shared` from `other_module.ts`. In short :

```
// shared.d.ts
declare module Shared { 
   export function SomethingElse(arg:string):any;
}
declare module 'shared'{ 
    export = Shared; 
}
```

And a typesafe import:

```
// other_module.ts

/// <reference path="shared.d.ts"/>
import Shared = require("shared"); 

export class Something {
    public someVar = new Shared.SomethingElse("blah");
}
```

## FIX B, as you were, but you need to use a different name then

Inside `other_module` don't use the name `Shared` locally if local scope *is global scope*. I recommend you just use external everywhere and compile for node with `commonjs` and browser with `amd` as shown in fix A, but if you must here is a compile fixed `other_module.ts`.

```
// other_module.ts
/// <reference path="shared.d.ts"/>
var fooShared: typeof Shared;
if(require) {  fooShared = require("shared"); }
else { fooShared = Shared; } 
export class Something {
    public someVar = new fooShared.SomethingElse("blah");
}
```

Comment: problem is I need to pollute the global namespace for use in the browser, the scenario is basically a data contract on a web service which is shared between server and client. So I just want 1 set of classes which can be used on both sides. So I have tried to write it in a way that if require etc is available it uses that, otherwise it  just relies upon the globals being in place. If I were to go down using the import route I need to use module loaders in the browser which is not the case. Also to use `import Shared` I need to use `export module` within shared lib, but it is MANY files.

Comment: Ah! your B example seems like it would work, will try that and report back +1 for ideas either way.

Comment: Seems to work, so this should get me over that hump at least, thanks for the help.